# Populated options from database doesn't run script on change

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, mysqli

I load the options for my select from a database (which loads the options) and am trying to run a script when the selected option changes (which doesn't run) the script is below

```
<script>
$(function()
{

    function subrace()
    {
        var race = $("#race").val();

        console.log(race + "!");
    }

    $("#race")
      .selectmenu()
      .selectmenu(
      {
          change:  subrace()
      })
      .selectmenu("menuWidget")
      .addClass("overflow");
 });
 </script>


<select name="race" id="race">
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "DanD_user";
$dbpass = "****************";
$dbname = "dand_user";

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM races ORDER BY name ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$x = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo"    <option value=\"" . $row['name'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>\n";
    $x++;
}

if($x === 0)
{
    echo"<option disabled selected>No Races Available</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

The script **is** in the head element and once I get the script to run I'll be adjusting it the console is just a peice to see if it runs

Comment: What is the .selectmenu() function?

Comment: @Rob its a jquery ui function

Comment: I see.  I noticed you're chaining it twice.  Not sure if thats the issue.

Comment: @Rob I pulled out the blank one with no difference in functionality and no it's no causing the problem and the one containing `menuWidget` is what changes the menu style

Answer (score 0):

Through working on my code further I discovered that the answer is that I can't just lay out the function I want to run in the situation I need to enclose it in another function

```
<script>
$(function()
{

    function subrace()
    {
        var race = $("#race").val();

        console.log(race + "!");
    }

    $("#race")
      .selectmenu()
      .selectmenu(
      {
          change:  function( event, ui )
          {
              subrace();
          }
      })
      .selectmenu("menuWidget")
      .addClass("overflow");
 });
 </script>


<select name="race" id="race">
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "DanD_user";
$dbpass = "****************";
$dbname = "dand_user";

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM races ORDER BY name ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$x = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo"    <option value=\"" . $row['name'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>\n";
    $x++;
}

if($x === 0)
{
    echo"<option disabled selected>No Races Available</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```